# How to purge BAM huawei mobile partner?

Tags: uninstall, network-manager, modem, purge

It annoying me every startup, now I use wvdial. I can't find it on synaptic package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are still interested...

Mobile Partner is not a standard .deb so it won't be present on Synaptic.

You need to use their dedicated script located here /usr/local/Mobile_Partner/UninstallMobilePartner

Comment: how to run that script